# Unable to delete old javaCompile action, maybe the class name has changed

Tags: java, android, gradle, rx-java, rx-android

I am learning RxJava. For that i followed [droidcon talk video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCLZ55M2gVo) on RxJava. The instructor has given [repo link](https://github.com/hamen/rxjava-essentials) for the project he was using. I cloned the repo when i try to build project in my machine. I get this error

> Error:Unable to delete old javaCompile action, maybe the class name
>   has changed? Please submit a bug report with what version of gradle
>   you are using.

Here is gradle.build file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:2.5.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://github.com/alter-ego/advanced-android-logger/raw/develop/releases/" }
}

apply plugin: 'retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.packtpub.apps.rxjava_essentials"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        abortOnError false
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'

    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.0'

    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.14.8'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava-joins:0.22.0'

    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'

    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.0.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'

    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'

}
```

Any idea how can i fix this issue?

Comment: @Zeshan Shabbir did you try this and add gradle jackOptions {
      enabled true
    } ??

Comment: @Javacoder yes i did but it doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 5):

The problem comes from [`RetroLambda`](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) plugin (see line 108 in [this link](http://codenav.org/code.html?project=/me/tatarka/gradle-retrolambda/2.5.0&path=/Source%20Packages/me.tatarka/RetrolambdaPluginAndroid.groovy)).

I assume upgrading plugin version would resolve your issue:

```
classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.1'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed classpath and now i get this error ```Error:(16, 0) Plugin with id 'retrolambda' not found.
<a href="openFile:/Users/Zeeshan/Desktop/personal/rxjava-essentials/rxjava_essentials_app/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>```

Comment: See all of **ReadMe** section in [Retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) github page and implement it appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one on app/build.gradle
Reference on [github](https://github.com/hamen/rxjava-essentials/issues/3)

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.4.0'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://github.com/alter-ego/advanced-android-logger/raw/develop/releases/" }
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.4.0'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.packtpub.apps.rxjava_essentials"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 22
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

        lintOptions {
            disable 'InvalidPackage'
            abortOnError false
        }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1"
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'

        compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.0'

        compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.14.8'
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'

        compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava-joins:0.22.0'

        compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'

        compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
        compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.0.0'

        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'

        compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'

    }
```

Comment: I had tried this before as well but this doesn't work as well.